# jQuery: append function is not working fine in webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

hi m trying to append a form which is in bootstrap (using jQuery append funciton),,, it has to open it once but is opening it twice and the button which is at the end of for shows one time and hide other time i just wants to show the form once by clicking once, and when i click again then it display again:" this is the current output i just wants that it show only once https://ibb.co/CtLrBzr  "

html code:

```
    <div class="col-md-4 create-task-btn1">
<span href="" class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon append">
<i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>
<br>
Assign Task
</span>
  </div>

  <div id="table-bordered">
  </div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.append').click(function() {
    $('#table-bordered').append(`<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
               <div class="row">
                <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 950px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                <td rowspan="3">
                                    <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div> 
           </div>`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 create-task-btn1">
  <span href="" class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon append">
          Assign Task
        </span>
</div>
```

Comment: i not see any `'#table-bordered'` element in your code..

Comment: sory i forget it during posting question now u can chk the updated question

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [one](https://api.jquery.com/one/) :

```
$('.append').one("click" , function(){ ... }
```

```js
$('.append').one("click", function() {
  $('#table-bordered').append(`<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
               <div class="row">
                <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 950px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                <td rowspan="3">
                                    <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div> 
           </div>`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 create-task-btn1">
  <span href="" class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon append">
<i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>
<br>
Assign Task
</span>
</div>

<div id="table-bordered">
</div>
```

Comment: still sane result

Comment: So you're saying that by using jQuery's `one()`, it's firing more than once?

Comment: I added a working snippet and the click handler triggers only once. Check by yourself.

Comment: its not like to show it once i mean whenever i click on it it opens a new form

Comment: it opens only once i wants that whenever i click then it opens

Comment: Then I'm completely lost with what you want. Your original question says `i just wants to show the form form once by clicking once` and now you say `i wants that whenever i click then it opens`. This is totally contradictory and I have no idea of the expected result.

Comment: check the snippt of @Yosef Tukachinsky he is right which thing i need

Comment: So... you want the form multiple times? Once every time you click the button? So why did you say in your original question `is opening it twice [...] i just wants that it show only once`? I'm still just as lost, man, this question is so unclear.

Comment: listen when i click then it ones the form twice i wants it opens once and when i click again then again open it once

Comment: Aaaaah so :
- Current behaviour : you click once, two forms are appended. You click again, two forms are appended again.
- Desired behaviour : you click once, only one form should be appended; you click again, only one other form is appended again.
Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".append").on("click", function(){
    $('#table-bordered').html();
});
```

Use your form inside the jquery html function. it will help you.

Comment: Ok. just write simple input box inside the html function and check it once if click event properly working or not.

Comment: plz chk the ans of 
@Yosef Tukachinsky  he is right he posted what i wants

Comment: every click you want to append form here. i thought you want only once.

Answer (score 0):

I just test your code and it's working fine..

Maybe you write the script before render the html? (mean in the head of the html, without defer)?

Make sure you add the script in the end of the body, or add the `defer` attribute there. otherwise when the script called, the button where you trying add a listener to is not exist in the moment when the script run

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.append').click(function () {
            $('#table-bordered').append(`<div class="container" style="margin-top:50px;">
               <div class="row">
                <form action="#" id="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: 950px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Task<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                <td rowspan="3">
                                    <a data-id="" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="" class="enable-tooltip btn" style="color: red; font-size: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" style="font-size: 14px;">Assigned To<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                                <th style="font-size: 14px;">Due Date<span class="text-danger">*</span></th>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="subject"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
           </div>`);
        });
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4 create-task-btn1">
<span href="" class="btn btn-info btn-lg dashboard-icon append">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i>
    <br/>
    Assign Task
</span>
</div>

<div id="table-bordered"></div>
```

Comment: did u make any changes init except js link addition bcoz its not working in my project but working here???

Comment: I not did any changes. As i say - maybe you put the script above the html instead below it? can it be?

Comment: where the script with the logic located in the page?

Comment: i add this <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 at the botom of page

Comment: the jquery script should be at the top (in the head). your custom script should be at the bottom of the body